# Is there a name for this property of binary operations?

Tags: terminology

Suppose we have a set $S$ with a binary operation $*$ such that for all $x,y,z$ $\in$ $S$, $(x*y)*z=(x*z)*y$. For example, subtraction on the integers and also the real numbers has this property. Is there a standard name for this property in the mathematical literature?

Comment: Not sure if there is a name for this, but it's a combination of associativity and commutativity. So if you have those properties, you have the one you want

Comment: Exponentiation has the property also.

Comment: This amounts to saying all of the operators $f_y : x \mapsto x * y$ commute.